# Start and end parameters in query label_values ​(filename) loki

Tags: api, grafana, dashboard, grafana-loki

I am setting up a logs grafana dashboard, and I would like to dynamically load the files that are generated in the logs directory into the dashboard selection variable via loki datasource.

I can load, but only log files that undergo modification are loaded.

After 1 day no longer appear.

---

26/11

[image: Input dashboard]

27/11

[image]

---

Know that api `loki/api/v1/label/filename` has the parameters
`start` `end`

[Loki API Documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/api/#get-lokiapiv1labels)

Consulting the api, I have the expected results

[image]

How can I pass these parameters in the query `label_values(filename)`?

[image]

I've tried `label_values({start: 1603506254000000000, end: 1607506254000000000}, filename)`, but it didn't work.

[image]

Would I have a way to spend an initial and final period, so that I could see all the files for the current month?

---

UPDATE:

I forwarded the question to github grafana / loki and it looks like an implementation that will be done in the future. https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/3011

Comment: Could you please describe what problem you are trying to solve by introducing this filename variable? May be there are better options to achieve the same result.

Comment: Hi nehaev, I edited the question, see if it makes more sense now.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to group log messages from Tomcat by filename, and it doesn't make much sense to me. Tomcat's log filenames are only different by time. But timestamp is anyway bound to each particular log record, so you can filter your logs by time range in Garafana without having to create this variable.

Answer (score 0):

> And log files that listed, after 1 day no longer appear.

I guess this is happening because in your config Grafana refreshes labels when dashboard is loaded. Probably Grafana takes labels from records loaded from Loki. And since the number of these records is limited (1000 by default), you are able to see only the most recent labels. You can try to increase this limit in data source config to check if my guess is correct and more labels appear.

Alternatively, you could try to refresh labels on time range changed (see the pic below), then proper labels should appear when you select the time range when they arrived on you dashboard. The query still would be `label_values​(filename)`.

[image: on time range change].

Comment: My datasource is configured for 1000000 records. Refresh actions are not related to loading the combo. I tested it here, and logs older than 1 day are not listing for me.

Comment: Let's distinguish log messages and labels. If you're unable to see log messages older than 1 day, it's either Grafana doesn't load them because of limit, or Loki drops them because of its table_manager.retention_period setting. If you CAN see old messages, but their label values are not loaded into variable (having config as I described in the answer), it looks like a bug in Grafana, please file it into their issue tracker.

Comment: I forwarded the question to github grafana / loki and it looks like an implementation that will be done in the future. https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/3011